# Spring jackson:date-format formatting changes after upgrade

Tags: spring-boot

After upgrading from spring boot 1.2.6.RELEASE -> 1.3.1.RELEASE there seems to be a problem when using iso 8101 dateformat with timezone offset.
In my application.yml the jackson date-format is set to format with timezone offset

```
spring:
   jackson:
      date-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

With boot 1.2.6 this results in datetime formats with the correct iso 8601 timezone format like 2014-01-01T23:01:01.010+01:00

But with boot 1.3.1 the format is kept in Zulu time zone
2014-01-01T22:01:01.010Z

Answer (score 2):

By default Jackson uses GMT time zone. You can change it by adding to your configuration file:

`spring:
  jackson:
    time-zone: Europe/Berlin`

or change it for certain property by using

`public class DateStuff {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd,HH:00", timezone="CET")
    public Date creationTime;
  }`

[Jackson FAQ: Date Handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling)

Comment: yeah generally i could, but in my case I don't have a domain model to annotate since it's basically a mongodb json app. cache with no knowledge of domains.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to @dimuha I figured it out. You have to add the time-zone property too to have the same behavior as before the upgrade

```
spring:
  jackson:
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
    time-zone: Europe/Berlin
```

This will output 2014-01-01T23:01:01.010+01:00 iso 8601 dates.